# How to prevent new Backlog items in Azure DevOps to automatically appear on Kanban board

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards, kanban

I am new to Azure DevOps and I am trying to create tasks and issues in the backlog first without appearing on the kanban board, and when tasks are ready they should appear on the kanban board. However every new task or issue I create they all appear on the kanban board. How can I prevent the tasks from automatically appearing on the Kanban board?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do that because the Kanban board is equal to your Backlog. You may consider:

1. Using tags to mark ready work items.
2. Add your custom state for issues then use it on the board: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops
3. Use another more complex process that contains all the needed states. As an example, Scrum:

[image]

Additionally, you can hide the New column:

[image]

Comment: The State for the first column cannot be changed for SCRUM as well, even when I create a new Inherited Process with new States. It seems like the first column must have the New State

Comment: @RahmanSaleh if you see an item in the backlog, you'll its ticket on the board.... this is how it works. You may hide the New column by clicking `<` on the board.... In this case, you create a new ticket (it is hidden by the New column). Then you add a description, and estimation and move the ticket to the Approved state. Then you see it on the board.

Comment: yes it took me a while to finally come to the conclusion that there is no way to not publish backlog items to the kanban board, and we can only hide them with the > char. It still seems weird though, I used Jira before and when you create a ticket it doesn't show on the board, the tickets move to the board only when they are approved which is more logical.